# How can I decrease the height of an HtmlTableRow?

Tags: c#, html-table, htmltable-control

I have one row in my HtmlTable that simply contains an "OR" string/label/LiteralControl. I want it to be shorter than the other rows to visually indicate the rows above and below are synonymous (you can fill in the row above OR the row below), and have tried several things (commented out):

```
// Create Row 5
var row5 = new HtmlTableRow();
//dynamicTable.Rows[4].Height = 12; // cannot implicitly convert int to str
//dynamicTable.Rows[4].Height = 12.ToString(); <= crash-o-rama
//row5.Height = 6; <= 'cannot convert int to string'
//row5.Height = "2cm"; // <= runs, but doesn't help
row5.Height = "2em";   // <= runs, but doesn't help
var cell5_1 = new HtmlTableCell();
row5.Cells.Add(cell5_1);

// Populate Row 5
LiteralControl orStr = new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OR");
cell5_1.Controls.Add(orStr);
dynamicTable.Rows.Add(row5);
```

...and none of them work - the row retains the same height regardless. How can I squish it down a bit?

Comment: What language/framework is this?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010 / C#